# VBA / INDEX MATCH - Partial data

Tags: vba, partial, index-match

my macro takes a long time to proceed and sometimes Excel blocks.

Tab A: list of specific languages in the "Database" tab (column A ).

Tab B: list of some virtual profiles (column D) including some beginning with a specific language "French ....".

What I need to do: mention in column 14 from Tab B these specific languages (if they exist).

I used below macro but it took sometimes up to 2mn when it works.
Do you know what I have to change? Thanks

```
    Worksheets("MyFile").Activate

    Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(Database!C[-17],MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(RC[-14],""*""&Database!C[-17]&""*""),),0))&"""""
    Range("R2").Select
```

Comment: If you [construct a `Dictionary`](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) of the languages in VBA, your lookup would be extremely fast. Can you guarantee that the "beginning" of a profile in Tab B/Column D contains the language text to be found in Tab A/Column A?  Also, how to [avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/4717755).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula is very long because it processes ALL the rows up to 1048576 (it basically treats the formula as an array / CSE formula because of `COUNTIF()`, which returns an array containing 1048576 values, in each cell the formula is calculated!). You need not to use an entire column reference. There is also an extra `INDEX()` that I removed. And you also need to filter out possible empty cells in the column containing the virtual profiles, that's why I am looking up for `2` in the `MATCH()`, not `1` anymore:

```
Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!C[-17],MATCH(2,(Database!R1C1:R1000C1<>"""")+COUNTIF(RC[-14],""*""&Database!R1C1:R1000C1&""*""),0))&"""",0)"
```

Note: you speak of column 14 in you tab/sheet named "MyFile", but that's column N not R

Comment: hope it will work for you specific case!

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Do you know how to remove "#N/A"?

Comment: Amazing!
I clicked on "useful" button but "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."